# Unable to get values from input form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html input:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputbox" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="inputbox" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
<button class="btn btn-red" onclick="logincheck();">LOG IN</button>
```

Javascripts:

```
function logincheck(){
     var e =  document.getElementById("email").value;
      p = $("#pass").val();
        console.log(e);

        if($("#email").val()==""||$("#pass").val()=="")
           alert("Email and password can't be empty");  
        else { 
            $.ajax({
                    url : "http://localhost/dsbd/loginprocess.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data : { 
                        email : e,
                        password: p
                        },
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function (data) { 
                            alert(data);

                        }
                });
            }
    }
```

`e` and `p` variables are returning empty string (while printing on console). 
Added the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr9hr411/)
 Please help me to find out the problem.

Comment: It's working just fine and dandy if you set jsFiddle to include the script without closures, as in *"nowrap in body"* etc -> http://jsfiddle.net/dr9hr411/2/

Comment: did you change anything on codes? It is returning empty string on my localhost.

Comment: Didn't change a thing, just made sure the function is within scope (global).

Comment: It works just fine. I am guessing you have another element with the same id somewhere in your page.

Answer (score 0):

In my opionion you just have to change your script (that is half javascript and half jquery with also some errors) in order to have a more clear code...

Here you have a working fiddle for jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my-login-button').click(function() {
    if($('#email').val().length == 0 || $("#pass").val().length == 0) {
      alert("Email and password can't be empty");  
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/dsbd/loginprocess.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : { 
          email : $('#email').val(),
          password: $("#pass").val()
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) { 
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputbox" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="inputbox" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
<button id="my-login-button" class="btn btn-red">LOG IN</button>
```

And here you have a javascript solution:

```js
function logincheck() {
  var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  console.log(e);
  
  if(e.length == 0 && p.length == 0) {
    alert("Email and password can't be empty");  
  } else { 
    $.ajax({
      url : "http://localhost/dsbd/loginprocess.php",
      type: "POST",
      data : {
        email : e,
        password: p
      },
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function (data) { 
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputbox" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="inputbox" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
<button id="my-login-button" onclick="logincheck()" class="btn btn-red">LOG IN</button>
```

Comment: Working on server but not on localhost. Thanks btw.

Comment: Worked for just a value. And again returning empty value. You can check it http://dsbangladesh.com and navigate to login.